# Making a typeclass, cannot deduce from context

Tags: haskell, typeclass

I'm using the [Servant](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/servant-server) libary, and I would like to automatically map results into error codes. Servant expects the type: `Either (Int, String) a`.

For example, if I have a model function of type: `IO (Maybe User)`. I would like to turn that in to `(404, "Not Found")` on Nothing, and the `User` if it's there.

To do this, I'm writing a typeclass!

```
class Servile a where
    toStatus :: ToJSON val => a -> Either (Int, String) val

instance ToJSON a => Servile (Maybe a) where
    toStatus Nothing  = Left (404, "Not Found")
    toStatus (Just a) = Right a
```

I have other instances I'd like to write, but this one gives me the error:

```
Could not deduce (a ~ val)
from the context (ToJSON a)
  bound by the instance declaration at Serials/Api.hs:90:10-38
or from (ToJSON val)
  bound by the type signature for
             toStatus :: ToJSON val => Maybe a -> Either (Int, String) val
  at Serials/Api.hs:91:5-12
  ‘a’ is a rigid type variable bound by
      the instance declaration at Serials/Api.hs:90:10
  ‘val’ is a rigid type variable bound by
        the type signature for
          toStatus :: ToJSON val => Maybe a -> Either (Int, String) val
        at Serials/Api.hs:91:5
Relevant bindings include
  a :: a (bound at Serials/Api.hs:92:20)
  toStatus :: Maybe a -> Either (Int, String) val
    (bound at Serials/Api.hs:91:5)
In the first argument of ‘Right’, namely ‘a’
In the expression: Right a
```

What's the right way to do this?

Comment: Shouldn't that be `toStatus :: ToJSON a => a -> Either (Int, String) a`?

Comment: I don't think so. I don't want to try to serialize `Maybe User` to json, I want to serialize the `User`. If I get a nothing I'm always doing a `Left`.

Comment: So maybe `toStatus :: ToJSON a => a -> Either (Int, String) JSON`?

Comment: How do you expect to convert `a` to any `ToJSON val => val`?  What your current typeclass is saying is that you want to be able to convert some `a` that implements `Servile` to any `ToJSON` type.  You could get around this by just having `toStatus :: a -> Either (Int, String) Value`.

Comment: Returning `Value`s directly means that you don't have to worry about being ambiguous.  Inside your `Servile` instances you have to worry about the conversion, but if what you're working with already implements `ToJSON` it's simple enough to do the conversion.  If what you're working with doesn't implement `ToJSON` then you have to handle it at the one place you care about that conversion.  Once that's done you can just call `toStatus` on everything without worrying about overlapping instances, incoherent instances, etc.  Keep it simple and just return a concrete type.

Comment: I like that! but it doesn't work because `Servant` asks me to outline the actual type I return and it doesn't match. `"sources" :> Capture "id" Text :> Get Source` ... it says `Couldn't match type Value with Source`

Comment: So, I'm still learning, and my typeclass-fu is weak. Why does my typeclass imply being able to convert any instance of `Servile` to ANY `ToJSON` type?  What I intended was to say: "You already have a ToJSON value somewhere in you, type! Convert yourself to either an error code or give me that value!"

Comment: @SeanClarkHess You are wanting to extract a `ToJSON val => val` from the `a`, but there are no restrictions on `a` to say that.  The `val` type variable only appears in the signature of `toStatus`, it has to come from nowhere currently.  Can you edit your question to show more of what you're trying to do?

Comment: Thank you for all your help @bheklilr! I'm sorry I didn't express the question very well. I shall upvote all your comments :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Another solution, if you want to work with some non-parameterized types, is to use `TypeFamilies`:

```
{-# LANGUAGE TypeFamilies #-}
{-# LANGUAGE FlexibleInstances #-}
module Temp where
import Data.Monoid

class ToStatus a where
  type Val a
  toStatus :: a -> Either (Int, String) (Val a)

instance ToStatus (Maybe a) where
  type Val (Maybe a) = a 
  toStatus Nothing  = Left (404, "Not Found")
  toStatus (Just v) = Right v

instance Show a => ToStatus (Either a b) where
  type Val (Either a b) = b 
  toStatus (Left e) = Left (500, "Server Error: " <> show e)
  toStatus (Right v) = Right v

instance ToStatus String where
  type Val String = ()
  toStatus "200 Success" = Right ()
  toStatus err = Left (500, err)
```

Comment: Wow cool! Is there an introduction to type families that you recommend?

Comment: @SeanClarkHess I like [Fun with type functions](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/um/people/simonpj/papers/assoc-types/fun-with-type-funs/typefun.pdf) a lot - also there is [Type Families and Pokemon](https://www.fpcomplete.com/school/to-infinity-and-beyond/pick-of-the-week/type-families-and-pokemon)

Answer (score 3):

I hopped on #haskell since I wasn't expressing the question very well. The issue is that it can't vary over any `a` to produce a `val` like that. It also turns out that `ToJSON` had nothing to do with this problem.

This works: Note that I changed `toStatus` to be `a val` instead of `a`, and the instances to remove the type variable.

```
class ToStatus a where
    toStatus :: a val -> Either (Int, String) val

instance ToStatus Maybe where
    toStatus Nothing  = Left (404, "Not Found")
    toStatus (Just v) = Right v

instance Show a => ToStatus (Either a) where
    toStatus (Left a) = Left (500, "Server Error: " <> show a)
    toStatus (Right v) = Right v
```